# Resize a pendrive Linux?

Tags: filesystem, partitioning, live-usb, resize

I'm running Ubuntu from USB media, which has a drive capacity of 250 GB, all existing as one FAT32 partition.

However, when I created the bootable Ubuntu drive, only 4.79 GB were allocated for usage.

Rather than put files directly into the /cdrom where the drive is mounted, I want to expand what is listed here in `aufs` to be at least 200 GB. I'm hopeful that I can do this live.

Output of `df` :

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
aufs                   4051904   4050108         0 100% /
none                   1542852       284   1542568   1% /dev
/dev/sdb1            244076800   4901648 239175152   3% /cdrom
/dev/loop0              688000    688000         0 100% /rofs
none                   1547840      1496   1546344   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1547840      4828   1543012   1% /tmp
none                   1547840        80   1547760   1% /var/run
none                   1547840         0   1547840   0% /var/lock
none                   1547840         0   1547840   0% /lib/init/rw
```

Output of `fdisk -l` :

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00083fe4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1       30401   244196001    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

So basically what I want to do is get `/dev/sdb1` to be entirely, or almost entirely read as `aufs`.

I'm confused over how to do this, as the file systems are all part of `/dev/sdb1` on one big partition, rather than separate partitions for separate file systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one was to re-size the partition to support the required space:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/
Which requires I shrink the partition, and create a new one.

This only really lets me use the new partition as a file system, so I have to re-mount directories onto the new partition.

You can follow along with something like this to mount non-boot related parts.
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/separatehome

The only issue is it won't keep the mount from following these instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Once I tried what you wish with no success.

After that, I made a new USB Startup Disk wit `usb-creator-gtk` (The USB Startup Disk Creator), and before making it I chosen "Stored in reserved extra space" under "When Starting up from this disk, documents and settings will be:", moved the slider to the right and made the startup disk.

After that, the disk features a partition in which the data is saved each time I work on it.

That way, I can use this disk to perform live sessions and save data or the day by day work.

In the next screenshot, the area that I refer above is grey as disabled, because of the Disk to use features 0.00 free bytes.

[image]